# Mapping definition for [suggest] has unsupported parameters: [payloads : true]

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I am using an example right from ElasticSearch documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-suggesters-completion.html#completion-suggester-mapping) using the Completion Suggestor but I am getting an error saying `payloads: true` is an unsupported parameter. Which obviously is supported unless the docs are wrong? I have the latest Elasticsearch app install (5.3.0).

Here is my cURL:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/search/pages/_mapping -d '{
"pages" : {
    "properties": {
        "title": { 
            "type" : "string" 
        },
        "suggest" : { 
            "type" : "completion",
            "analyzer" : "simple",
            "search_analyzer" : "simple",
            "payloads" : true
        }
    }
  }
}';
```

And the error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapping definition for [suggest] has unsupported parameters:  [payloads : true]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Mapping definition for [suggest] has unsupported parameters:  [payloads : true]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: For 5.3 the docs are different: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-suggesters-completion.html#completion-suggester-mapping and there is no `payloads` anymore.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Wow, don't I feel stupid now. Reading over those new docs, I don't see anything similar to payload. I need to have extra info added to the suggestions. Is there a way to do that? Also if you add this to answers I can mark it correct, lol.

Comment: Well, someone else already did the search and found the github issue about the removal of `payloads`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `payload`parameter has been removed in ElasticSearch 5.3.0 by the following commit: [Remove payload option from completion suggester](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/d107141bf6b50de1b448dd56be6faecf5005b7fb) . Here is the comit message:

```
The payload option was introduced with the new completion
suggester implementation in v5, as a stop gap solution
to return additional metadata with suggestions.

Now we can return associated documents with suggestions
(#19536) through fetch phase using stored field (_source).
The additional fetch phase ensures that we only fetch
the _source for the global top-N suggestions instead of
fetching _source of top results for each shard.
```